# Determining Required LUN Level Uniqueness

Tags: storage, iscsi, network-attached-storage, 3par

I have primarily used NFS for most of my storage needs but I find my self setting up some iSCSI targets today and had what is likely a super basic question.

When I create an export for an iSCSI target, the LUN I choose does it only have to be unique on this single target, or does it need to be unique on the entire storage network we have?

I was under the impression that when interfacing with iSCSI the end path is IQN with LUN attached to it, which led me to believe then that if I had 3 different arrays, theoretically each one could have an export, a unique IQN and still all have LUN 1 exposed and it wouldn't cause an issue if these three were used as compute storage/block storage etc